# C++ MySQL not returning ResultSet correctly

Tags: c++, mysql, resultset

So I have an SQL statement that runs perfectly on mySQL command, but when I execute that exact same statement in C++ it returns an empty ResultSet...

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
ps = con->prepareStatement("SELECT UserID, DB, IsAdmin FROM Users WHERE 
Username = ? AND Password = ?");

cout << "Username: ";
cin >> username;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
cout << "Password: ";
cin >> username;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
cout << endl;

ps->setString(1, username.c_str());
ps->setString(2, password.c_str());
rs = ps->executeQuery();
if (rs->next())
{
    connected = true;
    sessionID = rs->getInt(1);
    database = rs->getString(2).c_str();
    admin = rs->getBoolean(2);
}
```

`if(rs->next())` always evaluates `false`, no matter whether I use a normal Statement or a PreparedStatement. Even more weird is when I change the statement to just `SELECT * FROM Users` it does return rows. It can't be because of my  `WHERE` clause since it runs correctly on MySQL command. It still doesn't work when I remove `cin.ignore()` so that's not the problem either.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo.  When you ask for the password you are writing it to the username string.

```
cout << "Username: ";
cin >> username;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
cout << "Password: ";
cin >> username;
```

Change to:

```
cout << "Username: ";
cin >> username;
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
cout << "Password: ";
cin >> password;
```

Comment: Oh my god how did I not see this xD Thank you very much :D